# xslt boolean aggregation of a children property

Tags: xml, xslt, properties, boolean, aggregate

I would like to aggregate a boolean value which exists in all children of a node and add it to their parent.
My XML document looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module>
  <entity name="test" >
    <attributes name="att1" translatable="true">
    <attributes name="att2" translatable="false">
    <attributes name="att3" translatable="false">
    <attributes name="att4" translatable="true">
    </attributes>
  </entity>
</module>
```

And transform it to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module>

    <!-- 
        At the entity level the property translatable shall be the result of 
        the OR aggregation of all children attributes.translatable
        i.e. 
        iterate for all attributes (true OR false OR false OR true =  true ) ==> entity.translatable=true

    -->

<entity name="test" translatable="true">
    <attributes name="att1" translatable="true">
    <attributes name="att2" translatable="false">
    <attributes name="att3" translatable="false">
    <attributes name="att4" translatable="true">
    </attributes>
  </entity>
</module>
```

Comment: Please edit your source XML so that it is well-formed.

Comment: do you add translatable="true" in new xml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> iterate for all attributes (true OR false OR false OR true =  true )
>   ==> entity.translatable=true

There is no need to iterate - you only need to ask if there is at least one attribute with the value of *true*:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="entity">
     <entity name="{@name}" translatable="{boolean(attribute[@translatable='true'])}" >
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </entity>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above assumes a **well-formed** XML input such as:

```
<module>
  <entity name="test">
    <attribute name="att1" translatable="true"/>
    <attribute name="att2" translatable="false"/>
    <attribute name="att3" translatable="false"/>
    <attribute name="att4" translatable="true"/>
  </entity>
</module>
```